# Spring App is getting "Connection has already been closed" getting the length of a Blob

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic

I have a Spring app where Weblogic was upgraded from 12.2.1.0.0 to 12.2.1.4.0 and I started receiving the error "Connection has already been closed" on getting the Blob length after the upgrade.  I am running Spring 4.2.6 and Hibernate 5.0.1 in this app and Java 1.8.  I tried using a Stream but I was getting an Introspection Exception with the getter and setter for the blob when I try to change it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                       try {
                              usageList.addAll(dailyUsageUtils.convertEDMSBlobToUsageArray(interval
                                                          .getUsageBlob(), interval
                                                         .getIntervalCount(), interval.getSpi()
                                                          .longValue(), intervalStart.getTimeInMillis()));
                       } catch (SQLException e) {
                              throw new ProcessException("EDMS Interval data not valid");
                       }
```

Method: App is failing on blob.length

```
public List<DailyUsgBase> convertEDMSBlobToUsageArray(Blob blob, int totalIntervals, long spi, long start)
    throws SQLException
{ 
   
    List<DailyUsgBase> usageList = new ArrayList<DailyUsgBase>();
    final String timerId = "ConvertBlob";
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start(timerId);
    if (null != blob) {
           int blobLength = (int) blob.length();
           // double[] reads = new double[totalIntervals];
           byte[] blobBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
           blob.free();
           for (int x = 0; x < totalIntervals; x++)
           {
```

```
10:09:42.516 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
10:09:42.517 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAKFBAAA]
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 1
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAASPLAAE]
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 2
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAkZ7AAB]
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 3
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAqXaAAF]
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 4
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAA418AAJ]
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 5
10:09:42.526 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABA2IAAA]
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 6
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABK/NAAB]
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 7
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABTLeAAH]
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 8
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABld7AAH]
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 9
10:09:42.527 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABxUPAAC]
10:09:42.528 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAKFBAAA]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAKFBAAA]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAASPLAAE]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAASPLAAE]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAkZ7AAB]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAkZ7AAB]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAqXaAAF]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAAqXaAAF]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAA418AAJ]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAAA418AAJ]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABA2IAAA]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABA2IAAA]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABK/NAAB]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABK/NAAB]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABTLeAAH]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABTLeAAH]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABld7AAH]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABld7AAH]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABxUPAAC]
10:09:42.529 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.model.EdmsIntervalElectric#AABbRuAAAAABxUPAAC]
10:09:42.532 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
10:09:42.532 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG com.dukeenergy.itoa.common.dao.GenericDaoImpl - Cannot write hibernate statistics because statistics are not enabled. 
 Please 'set hibernate.generate_statistics=true' and 
 optionally set 'hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true'
10:09:42.532 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] INFO com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.service.impl.EdmsIntervalElectricServiceImpl - StopWatch: Edms Interval Retrieval : Edms Interval Retrieval : milliseconds to execute : 00:00:00.427
10:09:42.532 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - Disconnecting session
10:09:42.532 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
10:09:42.532 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection@e4]
10:09:42.533 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection@e4]
10:09:42.533 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection@e4] after transaction
10:09:42.533 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
10:09:42.534 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.service.impl.DailyUsageServiceImpl - Start java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1577854800000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2020,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
10:09:42.534 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] DEBUG com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.util.impl.DailyUsageUtilsImpl - Inside convertEDMSBlobToUsageArray Method
Oct 06, 2020 10:09:42 AM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed. EDMS Interval data not valid
com.dukeenergy.itoa.common.exceptions.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed. EDMS Interval data not valid
    at com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.service.impl.DailyUsageServiceImpl.getEdmsElectricUsage(DailyUsageServiceImpl.java:361)
    at com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.service.impl.DailyUsageServiceImpl.getUsage(DailyUsageServiceImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy379.getUsage(Unknown Source)
    at com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.endpoint.DailyUsageServiceEndpoint.getUsage(DailyUsageServiceEndpoint.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:120)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:246)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:386)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:163)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:286)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:295)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:103)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:250)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3793)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3763)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2451)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2299)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1720)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1680)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

<Oct 6, 2020 10:09:42,534 AM EDT> <Error> <com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler> <BEA-000000> <java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed. EDMS Interval data not valid
com.dukeenergy.itoa.common.exceptions.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed. EDMS Interval data not valid
    at com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.service.impl.DailyUsageServiceImpl.getEdmsElectricUsage(DailyUsageServiceImpl.java:361)
    at com.dukeenergy.sg.dailyusage.service.impl.DailyUsageServiceImpl.getUsage(DailyUsageServiceImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrk0A.png)

[Dependencies 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ffVi.png)

[Dependencies 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afW6H.png)

Comment: Can you provide more context to the exception? Provide full stacktrace and your dependencies?

Comment: Hi @gtiwari333 I added the stack trace and the dependencies.  Thanks!

Comment: It must be related to/caused by how you are creating DataSource/Connection/EntityManager etc objects to perform db query. I would look into the code around it and see the number of connection pool, how the connection is being opened/closed etc. Also, look for the compatibility of the spring/jpa/hibernate versions that you are using. I cannot provide a definitive answer unless you have https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Disabling "Wrap Data Types" for the datasource in the Weblogic server configuration fixed the error.

From Oracle:
Disable wrapping of data type objects

By default, data type objects for Array, Blob, Clob, NClob, Ref, SQLXML, and Struct, plus ParameterMetaData and ResultSetMetaData objects are wrapped with a WebLogic wrapper. You can disable wrapping which can improve performance and allow applications to use native driver objects directly. See Using Unwrapped Data Type Objects.

To disable wrapping of JDBC data type objects:

If you have not already done so, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Lock & Edit (see Use the Change Center).

In the Domain Structure tree, expand Services, then select Data Sources.

On the Summary of Data Sources page, click the data source name.

Select the Configuration: Connection Pool tab.

Scroll down and click Advanced to show the advanced connection pool options.

In Wrap Data Types, deselect the checkbox to disable wrapping.
Click Save.

To activate these changes, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Activate Changes.

Not all changes take effect immediately—some require a restart (see Use the Change Center).